# In Commerece 2.x can address be selected in the country's official language?

Tags: commerce

Upon setting up the address book, how can the select list of Country/Province/City etc. be displayed in the country's local language rather than in English?  e.g  廣東省　instead of Guangdong Sheng if China is selected as the Country?

Answer (score 0):

Country and subdivision translations are selected based on the current language. If your site language is "zh" you should be seeing the local labels.

For non-native languages the latin script alternative is shown for readability. If this is not working as I described, you can open an issue in the [address issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/address).